# Microservices changing log level dynamically

Tags: logging, microservices

I have a service which is running in a Docker container.

If I know where the container is running, then I have a way to dynamically change the logging level via REST API for that containerized service.

As my stateless Docker container is running in the cloud (Mesos and marathon), how do I go about changing the log level dynamically during run time for debugging? My services could be running anywhere in the cloud.